# How to organise and name code when working in MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am unsure when designing my code, should I be using class 'services' to bundle up logic for my View Model?

If I have a class that is responsible for providing view models with data about a user profile and triggering async api calls, should I place this in a file such as `ProfileService`?

The convention in Angular is something like `profile.service.ts` - would this class be called a 'Service'? Or is there a better pattern in Swift?

I am attempting my first iOS app using Swift. My background is Frontend web and I am keen to not bring across habits that are not best practice in Swift / iOS development.

An example would be something like this I guess:

```
class MyProfileService {
    func fetchUserProfile() {
        /*
            Perform some async network call
        */
    }
}

class MyViewModel {
    let profileService: MyProfileService
    init(profileService: MyProfileService) {
        self.profileService = profileService
    }
}

class MyClass {
    let viewModel = MyViewModel(profileService: MyProfileService())
}
```

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MVVM, you may want to use `Two Way data Binding` or `Observer-Listener` pattern between your `View` and `ViewModel`, You can refer to [MVVM Pattern](https://codeburst.io/swift-mvvm-two-way-binding-win-b447edc55ff5) for reference.

```
class MyProfileService {
    func fetchUserProfile() {
        /*
            Perform some async network call
        */
    }
}

class MyViewModel {
    var name: Observable<String?> = Observable()

    let profileService: MyProfileService
    init(profileService: MyProfileService) {
        self.profileService = profileService
    }
}

class MyClass {
    let viewModel = MyViewModel(profileService: MyProfileService())

    //observe the change in name property and do your task
    viewModel.observe(for: [viewModel.name]) { [weak self] (_) in
        // perform your task once name property is set
    }
}
```